# is there any way to distribute the app to clients without adding his UDID?

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store, udid

My app is in final stage of testing ,i want to distribute the app to my clients without adding their UDIDs. I understand that there is a facility called enterprise developer program which permits in house distribution of apps and also ad hoc distribution. Is there any way in which i can distribute the app to my clients without adding UDID,who inturn submits to the app store on their behalf.

TNQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YES.

Your client can obtain their own iOS Developer enrollment and certificates (either regular, company or Enterprise).  Then you can send them your app, which doesn't have to be signed with a provision that includes their UDIDs, and they will be able re-sign the app using one of their own mobileprovisions.  Or put it in their private app store if they get an Enterprise enrollment.  They can also re-sign your app with their own Distribution profile and submit it to the app store themselves.

If anyone has the SDK installed on their Mac, plus a developer enrollment, they can re-sign anyone's developer or Ad Hoc apps using the codesign utility from the Terminal command line.  (Thus, a developer should be careful about to whom they distribute their Ad Hoc apps for beta testing.)

Comment: so anyone who has the 'ad-hoc' app builds i have sent, can upload it to itunes with their own 'app-store' profile???? thats scary.. its like they own my apps..

Comment: @hotpaw2 can u share few details of enterprise developer account.how will apple know and ensure that i am distributing apps within the organisation.speaking frankly i do not know how to distribute apps within organisation using enterprise account,whether udid is to be mentioned etc,even googling didn't help to answer myself.

Comment: Enterprise accounts are only for corporations large enough for a D&B rating.  That likely means there is a company attorney (chief consul, etc.) to determine license compliance policy.  Do what that lawyer says.

Answer (score 3):

NO.

you can do that only with enterprise program, but with enterprise program, you cant submit apps to app store.. its for in-house distribution only...

so... client doesn't want to share iOS developer credentials with you.. you don't want to share the code with client...

well you can tell him to create app store provisioning profile and send it to you... you can build the app with that profile and send it to the client and he can add all the details and upload it